# Parent/Child database contains cyclical references

Tags: python, mysql, directed-acyclic-graphs, topology

I have a keyword table where each keyword is assigned an id and is unique. I have a second table that links ids of parent keywords to ids of child keywords. One keyword can have up to approx 800 children or have none at all. Children can be parents of yet more keywords (and on and on...)

The issue I am running into is a child (or grandchild or great grandchild) can be the parent of the initial keyword causing a cyclical structure. I am attempting to build a tree data structure for the initial keyword using a recursive function but the function either never ends, or goes past the 1000 level recursion limit in Python.

Is there a better way to design my parent/child table to prevent this (or do upfront checking during inserts) or is there a better way to write a recursive function to prevent this condition from happening? I tried to limit the depth of the recursion function but ran into single level issues (i.e. child being the parent of the parent). Again, my goal is to create a tree structure for an initial keyword.

```
Table Keyword:
    id int(11) not null primary key auto_increment (id of keyword)
    text varchar(255) unique (keyword text e.g. "computer help desk")

Table Keyword_Relation:
    id int(11) not null primary key auto_increment (id for parent/child combo, not keyword id)
    parent int(11) (id of parent keyword)
    child int(11) (id of child keyword)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start at the top of the tree, and just keep track of the nodes you've already found and ignore them.

```
def getchildren(node, ignore_nodes=[]):
    child_nodes = []
    for child in node.children():
        if child in ignore_nodes:
            continue
        child_nodes.append(child)
        ignore_nodes.append(child)
        nodes, ignore_nodes = getchildren(child, ignore_nodes)
        child_nodes.extend(nodes)
    return child_nodes, ignore_nodes
```

Comment: if he ignores them then he isn't very well checking if he has cycles.

Comment: @Matthew  The question asks how to get all children of a node, even if there are cyclical references; this does that.  It ignores cyclical references, preventing infinite recursion.  If the goal is to prevent cyclical references in the first place (though I'm not sure that is the question), then yes, this wouldn't prevent that.

Comment: @Brendan I guess I misunderstood the question. I read it that he wanted to check for or prevent the cycles. I can also see that he wants all child nodes. Your solution is great for the latter... and, from the OP's comment, it looks like that's all he really needed anyhow. +1

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is create a topological sort. There are a number of methods published for doing this optimally and it will depend on your schema and preferred method.

In your case it sounds like you do not have multi-parent.
But how I have dealt with it programmatically is to start with the leaf nodes (that is nodes with no children) and ascend the tree.
While ascending, keep a collection of nodes you have encountered. If you ever repeat an encounter then a cycle exists and a topological sort is not possible.

You will not get an infinite loop, but it's certainly possible that your topology will have more than 1000 nodes... so recursion may not be possible for you.

**EDIT:** To answer your question about "better design".... If possible it may be advantageous to store the root node identifier.
That is: given a parent, child, grandchild, greatgrandchild, greatgreat....grandchild

Each row will not only contain their *immediate* parent's ID but also the *root node* Parent ID... or some "known good" root node

IF you do this you can speed up topological sort methods by only ascending up until the root node, and only include sets having the same root node.

Comment: You can extend the python recursion limit -- http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit -- it's mainly to prevent infinite recursion.  As long as you know your topology has a finite number of nodes, it should be safe.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are multi-parents in my database. Also, for example, keyword 219 is a child of keyword 1 but keyword 1 is also a child of keyword 219. It sounds like a topological sort is not possible because of these closed loops. It actually doesn't matter that the resultant tree contains ALL possible children, just that it contains some (large) sub-set of possible children.

Comment: Adding a "root node" field would open up the database to update anomalies.  If a "root node" is assigned a parent, all nodes that reference that record as a root node would now be incorrect.  You would have extra overhead trying to keep the "root node" column correct, rather than just ascending the node tree on demand.

Comment: @DaveO your example is a cycle, not a multi-parent. Multi-parent means that 219 is a direct child of more than one other record. Cycles are specifically what you're trying to prevent....

Comment: @Brendan when you update a root node, you must also update all rows having that root node. This isn't an update anomaly; it's also quite simple. Tracking different levels in the DAG otherwise requires traversal.

Comment: @Matthew PK
It wouldn't just be the root nodes, updating the parent relationship of *any* node would require updating the "root node" field on all child nodes as well.  It's essentially database denormalization, which is fine for special cases, but for general use, is always less efficient.

Comment: @Brendan it's still just 2 SQL statements. And yes, it is *absolutely* denormalized. The qualifying factor is how much time you can save ascending the tree if you know the root node already.